# Can't retrieve value from Django Template (.html) to my views

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to develop an apllication that deals with learning objects metadata. One of the functions of the system is to view the L.O. metadata in browser.

I have an HTML template that lists the result of the query from the database. Each result come along with a "Visualize Metadata" button, that when clicked, should display the metadata of that object in browser. So I want my button to pass the object ID back to my view, so i can make another query by the specific ID and print the results on the screen.

This is my template .html

```
    {% if objects %}
    <ul>
    {% for object in objects %}
        <li> 
            {{ object.General.title }}
            <form action='visualize' method='POST' name='id' value="{{object.General.id}}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" >Visualize Metadata </button>
            </form> 
            
        
        </li>

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No results found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And this is my views.py function

```
def visualize_lom_metadata(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        objID = request.POST.get('id')
        return HttpResponse(objID)
```

For now i just want to see if that's possible by printing the objID in the screen. But when I try to do that,it just returns "None". Anyone knows how to retrieve data from template.html to my Django views.py?

Comment: If still relevant then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73855943/15249596) nice solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe that all your forms should have different names and ids, and that submit button must be bound to that form.

It would also help if you in your visualize_lom_data would print entire request.POST to see what you get back from template.